# Create a folder which can be written to but not read

Tags: permissions, chmod, shared-folders, setfacl

I've been going over content I previously used in Uni to learn Linux, as I have gotten rusty and thought a refresher would be helpful. The content is hosted on a site similiar to Hack the Box which is able to deploy linux boxes and by clicking a check button on the site, it will verify you have done a specific challenge correct. The box I am using is CentoOS 7 based.

The exact question I am currently stuck on is:

> Create a directory /root/dropzone It should be set up so that group and other users can save files in the directory, but they cannot read the files that are there. User root must able to read and write the directory.

The content so far (related to permissions) has covered `chmod`, `setfacl`, and `umask`. So it should be possible with these. However the closest I've been able to get is to allow another user to delete the dropzone folder. No matter what I do, I cannot seem to allow other users to write to the directory, and always get an error like the following:

```
touch: cannot touch ‘/root/dropzone/test’: Permission denied
```

While having permissions of:

```
drw-rw-rw-. 2 root root 17 Mar  9 13:45 /root/dropzone/*
```

(I know these are not exactly what the question is asking for but I was attempting to troubleshoot where the root cause could be to no success)

Umask is still the default `0022` however I'm not convinced this is related?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/root`?  If "others" can't access `/root`, then they cannot find `/root/dropzone`.  Looking at my machine the permissions are `dr-xr-x---.  13 root   root    4096 Mar  9 12:09 root` which blocks anyone outside the root group.

Comment: Here is a good, detailed answer:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/134169/how-can-i-make-a-write-only-view-of-a-folder

Comment: @Martin Currently at dr-xr-xrw-. however even when I had them set to drwxrwxrwx. I got the same results